# Сравнение части массивов C#

Tags: c#, массивы

Всех приветствую. Подскажите пожалуйста, как проверить массивы разной длины на совпадение определенного количества элементов (с нулевого элемента)? У меня есть два массива типа byte и нужно, убедиться, что один из них совпадает с другим, например, на 10 байт.
В обычном C я для этого использовал
`memcmp(массив1, массив2, кол-во байт)`
В C# я такой функции не нашел, нужно подключать DLL, чтобы это сработало. Может есть какой-то штатный метод?

Comment: System.Linq `if (a.Take(n).SequenceEqual(b.Take(n)))`

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal

Comment: Можно конечно и сам memcmp вызвать https://stackoverflow.com/a/3718193/12888024, он быстрее отработает чем SequenceEqual, но поддерживает только байты, а SequenceEqual - что угодно.